# OpenCV absdiff() Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: opencv

I have error on `absdiff(grayImg, bgImg, diffImg);` 
and I don't understand why this is wrong.

```
VideoCapture capture;
capture.open(0);

if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    printf("error\n");
    return -1;
}

Mat grayImg;
Mat diffImg;
Mat bgImg = imread("BgImg.jpg");
Mat frame;

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

for (;;) {
    capture >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, grayImg, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    absdiff(grayImg, bgImg, diffImg);
    threshold(diffImg, diffImg, 50, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    findContours(diffImg, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    drawContours(frame, contours, -1, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 8);
    imshow("capture", frame);
    imshow("diffImg", diffImg);

    char chKey = waitKey(10);
    if (chKey == 27) break;

}
destroyAllWindows();
return 0;
```

Comment: Why don'y you try making a [minimum viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then [edit your question with that and explain what you tried and where you're stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Thanks, and welcome to SO!

Comment: Do some debugging and inspect the size and number of channels of the two input parameters to `cv::absdiff`.